# LuaTeX change the catcode of numbers

Tags: luatex, catcodes

I'm trying to check if a label is defined with \ifdefine \r@labelname.
The label is a hexadecimal number like 215Bh and this does not work.
So I tried to change the catcodes of the numbers to 11

But I'm getting errors on the line `` \catcode`\2=11 `` because 1 is no number any more:

```
./mwe.tex:12: Missing number, treated as zero.
```

If I reorder the catcode lines to change the code of 1 at the end, I'm getting the problem when switching back with `\catcodetable 0`

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \label{test}
    \label{215Ah}
    \initcatcodetable 3
    \makeatletter
    \catcode`\0=11
    \catcode`\1=11
    \catcode`\2=11
    \catcode`\3=11
    \catcode`\4=11
    \catcode`\5=11
    \catcode`\6=11
    \catcode`\7=11
    \catcode`\8=11
    \catcode`\9=11
    \ifdefined \r@test test is  defined \fi
    \ifdefined \r@215Ah  215Ah is  defined \fi
    \catcodetable 0
    \makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: To solve this specific case `\ifcsname` is the easiest

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the LaTeX internal `\@ifundefined`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \label{test}
    \label{215Ah}
    \makeatletter
    test is \@ifundefined{r@test}{undefined}{defined}.
    215Ah is \@ifundefined{r@215Ah}{undefined}{defined}.
    tongo is \@ifundefined{r@tongo}{undefined}{defined}.
    \makeatother
\end{document}
```

or without `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` you can use `\ifcsname`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \label{test}
    \label{215Ah}
    test is \ifcsname r@test\endcsname defined\else undefined\fi.
    215Ah is \ifcsname r@215Ah\endcsname defined\else undefined\fi.
    tongo is \ifcsname r@tongo\endcsname defined\else undefined\fi.
\end{document}
```

But if you really want to fiddle with `\catcode` you can use:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*{\makeatanddigitsletter}{%
  \makeatletter
  \catcode`\0=\catcode`\@
  \catcode`\1=\catcode`\@
  \catcode`\2=\catcode`\@
  \catcode`\3=\catcode`\@
  \catcode`\4=\catcode`\@
  \catcode`\5=\catcode`\@
  \catcode`\6=\catcode`\@
  \catcode`\7=\catcode`\@
  \catcode`\8=\catcode`\@
  \catcode`\9=\catcode`\@
}
  
\begin{document}
\label{test}
\label{215Ah}
\begingroup
  \makeatanddigitsletter
  test is \ifdefined \r@test defined\else undefined\fi.
  215Ah is \ifdefined \r@215Ah defined\else undefined\fi.
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use catcode tables, but you need some trick.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
\def\setcodeletter#1{\catcode`#1=11 }
\setcodeletter @
\setcodeletter 0
\setcodeletter 1
\setcodeletter 2
\setcodeletter 3
\setcodeletter 4
\setcodeletter 5
\setcodeletter 6
\setcodeletter 7
\setcodeletter 8
\setcodeletter 9
\savecatcodetable \string 3
\endgroup

\expandafter\def\csname r@215Ah\endcsname{AAA} % emulate having read the .aux file

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\catcodetable 3
\ifdefined \r@test test is defined\else test is undefined\fi

\ifdefined \r@215Ah 215Ah is defined\else 215Ah is undefined\fi
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

The manual specifies that and `\savecatcodetable` acts globally. So the command `\setcodeletter` will disappear.

Beware of `\catcodetable 0`, because it doesn't set necessary catcodes for braces and other special characters (it's the same as the assignments when iniTeX starts off).